# How do i put this data in my DB?

Tags: database, cakephp

i have an array in $this->data that looks like this:

```
    Array
(
    [Boeking] => Array
        (
            [start] => 25/12/2010
            [end] => 26/12/2010
            [centrum] => Brussels
            [responsible] => Wouter
            [email] => bla@bla.bla
            [materials] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 6
                    [3] => 8787
                    [4] => 5
                    [5] => 2572
                    [6] => 75
)
)
)
```

the fields in my DB are the same, so i have a table called 'boekings', with the fields 'start, end, centrum, responsible, email and materials'.

materials is a varchar(1000) so it should be long enough.

without CakePHP i used to do this with the serialize() function of php, but now i don't know the answer...

when i comment the line responsible for the materials array, it puts the data properly in my DB so there is no problem with my saveAll() method.

Thanx in advance guys!

Wouter

Answer (score 0):

never mind got this working allready

http://cakeqs.org/eng/questions/view/how_do_i_put_this_data_in_my_db

thanx!

Comment: This is bad style, you should add a table Boeking_material which relate materials to the Boekings (whatever those are). Storing data serialized or comma seperated in databases might work but it _will_ bite you later (i.e. when you want to search for boekings with specific materials).